# Run JS file to get first available port in npm script

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json

I've the following script in my `package.json`:

```js
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js --progress --port ${getPort()}",
```

And I've installed a package [get-port](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-port) that allows you to set a default port and take another one that's available if the default isn't.

I'd like to use this dependency to get the port for the script above (where you see `getPort()`). What can I do to run JS inline and get the return value from a function?

Comment: Maybe use the CLI version of the package? https://github.com/sindresorhus/get-port-CLI It's linked at the bottom of the page that you linked...

Comment: @CherryDT I missed that, thanks for pointing it out. Ran into an error on install... https://github.com/sindresorhus/get-port-cli/issues/7

Comment: You could also try something like `PORT=$(node -e 'require("get-post").then(console.log)')`

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a full example? Not sure where to put this

Comment: First of all, sorry I had some typos there, should be `node -e 'require("get-port")().then(console.log)'`. Full example: `webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js --progress --port $(node -e 'require(\"get-port\")().then(console.log)')`

Answer (score 1):

Random ports are not a good idea, especially if you integrate with other services like Facebook API. You could just use a gulp script to kill the process on your port.

Can you try to set it to auto in webpack? https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverport

---

If you want it your way, I would create a gulp script to execute `get-port` and then run the ng serve using that port.
Make sure you have gulp and get-port installed. Sample code but not tested

```
const getPort = require('get-port');
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
var gulp = require('gulp'); 

async function serveMe() {
    gulp.task('serve', function (cb) {
      exec("webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js --progress --port " + await getPort(), function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log(stderr);
        cb(err);
      });
    })
}


exports.serveMe = serveMe;
```

package.json

```
"start": "gulp serveMe",
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally I'd say, use the [CLI version of the package](https://github.com/sindresorhus/get-port-CLI) so you can easily call it from a shell script. However, since you seem to have encountered issues with installing `get-port-CLI`, here is an alternative solution:

You can use `node -e <script code>` to execute code inline, in that case `require('get-port')().then(console.log)`:

```sh
webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js --progress --port $(node -e 'require(\"get-port\")().then(console.log)')
```